# show animation on button click flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a column of buttons on my app. The middle button needs to be animated. So basically when the user taps I need to show an animation.

[image]

As you can see the heart button has two parts. Anything below the heart button is fixed. Anything above the heart button is animated. So the 9 should only be visible when the actual button is tapped.

This is my code for reaction_button so far:

```
        Column(
          children: [
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                child: CounterCard(count: userLikeCount),
              ),
            ),
            LikeButton(
              size: 40,
              animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              likeCountAnimationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
              bubblesColor: const BubblesColor(
                dotPrimaryColor: Colors.red,
                dotSecondaryColor: Colors.red,
              ),
              circleColor: const CircleColor(
                start: Colors.pink,
                end: Colors.pink,
              ),
              likeBuilder: (isLiked) {
                return SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/icons/heart.svg",
                  color: buttonColor,
                );
              },
              onTap: (isLiked) => increment(isLiked),
            ),
            Text(
              likeCount.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

```
  Future<bool> increment(bool isLiked) async {
    setState(() {
      likeCount++;
      userLikeCount++;
      buttonColor = Colors.pink;
    });
    if (userLikeCount >= 100) {
      userLikeCount = 100;
    }
    setState(() {
      isVisible = true;
    });
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 800)).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        isVisible = false;
      });
    });
    return true;
  }
```

For now when the user presses the button a simple CountCard is shown which disappears after 1 second. What I need to add is an up going(I dont know the word for it, FadeUp animation?). I made the disappearing part work.

thanks to **@yeasin_sheikh** this is what I have managed so far:

```
  AnimatedContainer(
     transform: animation.value,
     color: Colors.red,
     duration: controller.duration!,
     child: Visibility(
        visible: isVisible,
        child: CounterCard(count: userLikeCount),
     ),
   ),
```

for on tap

```
    controller.forward();
    setState(() {
      isVisible = true;
    });
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) {
      controller.reverse();
      setState(() {
        isVisible = false;
      });
    });
```

and initialized:

```
  late final controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200))
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  late final animation = Tween<Matrix4>(
          begin: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 30, 0), end: Matrix4.identity())
      .animate(controller);
```

The result is as:

[Result](https://www.veed.io/view/77e01a5d-8c51-4315-8577-4c518beb519f?sharingWidget=true)

All the buttons are moving which I don't like much and if the user presses the react button quickly the animation gets all fuzzy. So, any suggestions regarding those are highly appreciated.

Comment: can you include sample but full widget

Comment: I am sorry but all I have is the figma but as it's confidential I can't share it. But when the heart button is pressed a value(ex: 9/10/11) will appear and go up(very much like the fade out animation).

Comment: It's ok, the LikeButton can be switched with any button? It would be easier if could include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yes like button is pretty simple. Takes a call back function called onTap and the entire LikeButton is wrapped with GestureDetector.

Comment: Hey I have updated the code. I need the CountCard to go up a few pixels and disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this widget for basic animation, better might be using AnimationBuilder.

```dart
class TAn extends StatefulWidget {
  const TAn({super.key});

  @override
  State<TAn> createState() => _TAnState();
}

class _TAnState extends State<TAn> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final controller =
      AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200))
        ..addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
        });
// I was curious if Matrix4 will work or not 
  late final animation = Tween<Matrix4>(
          begin: Matrix4.translationValues(0, 48, 0), end: Matrix4.identity())
      .animate(controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            AnimatedContainer(
              transform: animation.value,
              color: Colors.red,
              duration: controller.duration!,
              child: Text("6."),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.forward();
              },
              child: Text("show "),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.reverse();
              },
              child: Text(" hide"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code and added a sample video of the near end product